# How to use an EmbedMessage From a Different File?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm having trouble with an embedmessage. I provided my code below of my index.js in which I'm trying to use a function made in "globalspeakfunction.js".

Don't worry about the variables I'm sending they look extra in this but I only provided the relevant code to hopefully reduce confusion.

I'm building up my EmbedMessage in GlobalSpeakFunction.js and then sending it in the channel of the message provided in "index.js".

However my console gives back "cannot send empty message" and when I do a console.log of the EmbedMessage it returns the embed perfectly?

I tried adding a string "test" after my embedmessage in the send() function and then it returned

```
[object Object]test
```

I have no idea what's going on here. Am I not able to buildup an EmbedMessage in a different file and then send it back to my bot? Or is there something I'm just overlooking?

**index.js**

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const speak = require('../GlobalSpeakFunction.js');

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes(`test`)){
        speak("778978295059972106", message, "test", "Default");
    }
}
```

**GlobalSpeakFunction.js**

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = function speak(charID, data, message, emotion){
    var EmbedMessage = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#0099ff')
        .setTitle('title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setDescription(message)
        .setThumbnail('https://drive.google.com/file/d/17J90PzTLBR96wTwk_Wl3U06-or6ZjPW2/view')
        .setTimestamp();
    message.channel.send(EmbedMessage);           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure where you experienced the 'Cannot send an empty message' error, I can't reproduce it locally. However, there are a few issues here:

Firstly, you're using `toUpperCase()` on `message.content`, and later checking whether it includes (lowercase) "test". Thus, this if statement will never execute.

Secondly, the order of arguments in the `speak()` function is `charID, data, message, emotion`, but you're passing them as `"778978295059972106", message, "test", "Default"` (notice how `data` and `message` are swapped when calling the function).

Thirdly, the `setThumbnail()` function expects a direct link to an image (one that ends with a file extension, like .png or .jpg). You're providing a Google Drive link, which is additionally set to private, which makes it unreadable for anyone but you. I'd recommend uploading it to an image host and getting the direct link from there.

Also, `[object Object]` is just a string representation of an object. JavaScript tries to convert your MessageEmbed (which is an object) to a string (because you're trying to append 'test' to it).

Comment: The 'Cannot send an empty message' error appears when you try to send a falsy value, such as `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: I know, but I haven't been able to get it while using this code - it seems like the Embed was constructed properly, at least in this call of `speak()`.

Comment: the toupper and tolower confusion is my bad. I replaced the content of includes() with test for showcasing the code above.

it might seem confusing that data becomes the message and message becomes "test" but this is correct still.

setThumbnail does work even tho the image is private.. not sure how that works?

the "cannot send an empty message" error is in my console and I am trying to break my head over it too I have no idea how or why it is doing that.

Comment: @Xeoth oh, my bad

Comment: changing the 
message.channel.send(EmbedMessage);
to
message.channel.send({ embed: EmbedMessage })
worked!